# Java File IO performance dropped over 30% when adding lots of JARs into classpath

Tags: java, file, io

**Test Code:**

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Map.Entry;

public class ReadLine {

    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        System.getenv();
        System.getProperties();

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(args[0]), 2 << 17);
        int lineTotal = 0;
        int lineDone = 0;
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long totalSincePre = System.currentTimeMillis();
        while (br.readLine() != null) {
            lineTotal++;
            if (lineTotal % 100000 == 0) {
                long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
                System.out.println("total speed=" + lineTotal / (end - totalSincePre) + "k/s. curr speed="
                        + (lineTotal - lineDone) / (end - start));
                start = end;
                lineDone = lineTotal;
            }
        }
        printEnv();
    }

    static void printEnv() {

        for (Entry<?, ?> e : System.getenv().entrySet()) {
            System.out.println(e.getKey() + ":" + e.getValue());
        }

        for (Entry<?, ?> e : System.getProperties().entrySet()) {
            System.out.println(e.getKey() + ":" + e.getValue());
        }
    }
}
```

**Test Env:**
OS: Linux, File Size: 7.2G (csv text file, Over 1k per line), java version "1.6.0_32"

**Test Run:**

The code is packaged into one jar. I ran following two test on the same host, using the same jar, reading the same file.

1) Run `./java -cp=my.jar ReadLine TestFile.txt`
The performance stabilized at about 150k line /s.

Console output is like:

```
total speed=251k/s. curr speed=251
total speed=304k/s. curr speed=384
total speed=323k/s. curr speed=371
total speed=337k/s. curr speed=387
total speed=350k/s. curr speed=414
total speed=358k/s. curr speed=401
total speed=363k/s. curr speed=395
total speed=349k/s. curr speed=277
total speed=304k/s. curr speed=150
total speed=277k/s. curr speed=153
total speed=258k/s. curr speed=154
total speed=244k/s. curr speed=152
total speed=233k/s. curr speed=152
total speed=225k/s. curr speed=154
total speed=218k/s. curr speed=153
total speed=196k/s. curr speed=149
total speed=193k/s. curr speed=146
......stabled.......
total speed=163k/s. curr speed=150
total speed=162k/s. curr speed=155
total speed=162k/s. curr speed=155
total speed=162k/s. curr speed=149
total speed=162k/s. curr speed=147
total speed=162k/s. curr speed=150
total speed=161k/s. curr speed=148
total speed=161k/s. curr speed=145
total speed=161k/s. curr speed=151
total speed=161k/s. curr speed=154
total speed=161k/s. curr speed=163
total speed=161k/s. curr speed=179
```

2) No code changes, just added JARs (used in production environment) into classpath (needed in production, but not it this program), like `./java -cp=my.jar:hundreds_of_other_jars ReadLine TestFile.txt`. The performance dropped to about 90k line /s

```
total speed=312k/s. curr speed=383
total speed=335k/s. curr speed=393
total speed=348k/s. curr speed=395
total speed=361k/s. curr speed=423
total speed=369k/s. curr speed=414
total speed=374k/s. curr speed=404
total speed=342k/s. curr speed=214
total speed=264k/s. curr speed=93
total speed=224k/s. curr speed=95
total speed=200k/s. curr speed=95
total speed=182k/s. curr speed=94
total speed=170k/s. curr speed=94
total speed=161k/s. curr speed=95
total speed=154k/s. curr speed=95
total speed=148k/s. curr speed=93
.....stabled.....
total speed=139k/s. curr speed=92
total speed=135k/s. curr speed=92
total speed=132k/s. curr speed=92
total speed=129k/s. curr speed=92
total speed=127k/s. curr speed=92
total speed=125k/s. curr speed=90
total speed=123k/s. curr speed=91
total speed=121k/s. curr speed=92
total speed=120k/s. curr speed=89
total speed=118k/s. curr speed=92
total speed=117k/s. curr speed=91
total speed=116k/s. curr speed=91
total speed=115k/s. curr speed=91
total speed=114k/s. curr speed=90
total speed=113k/s. curr speed=91
```

My analysis:

The ONLY difference is classpath. The second test's classpath has hundreds of JARs in classpath. But none of them is used in this program.

- Not environment related. This code is packaged into the JAR and both tests used the same JAR. Both tests run on the same host, read the same file, use the same code. I also compared the System.getEnv and System.getProperties, no difference other than classpath.
- Not OS cache. This can be reproduced. After many tests, the results are the same. No matter which test ran first.
- jmap shows the memory usage has no big difference and all generations are not highly used.
- jstack shows the call stack for both test is most likely to be as

this

```
at java.io.FileInputStream.available(Native Method)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.inReady(StreamDecoder.java:343)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:304)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:158)
 - locked <0xb4220388> (a java.io.FileReader)
at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:167)
at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:136)
at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:299)
- locked <0xb4220388> (a java.io.FileReader)
at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:362)
at com.amazon.invhealth.metrics.transform.topasin.RL.main(RL.java:24)
```

or

```
at sun.nio.cs.UTF_8$Decoder.decodeArrayLoop(UTF_8.java:240)
at sun.nio.cs.UTF_8$Decoder.decodeLoop(UTF_8.java:305)
at java.nio.charset.CharsetDecoder.decode(CharsetDecoder.java:544)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:298)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:158)
- locked <0xb4220388> (a java.io.FileReader)
at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:167)
at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:136)
at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:299)
- locked <0xb4220388> (a java.io.FileReader)
at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:362)
at com.amazon.invhealth.metrics.transform.topasin.RL.main(RL.java:24)
```

Looking at the call stack these test cases are likely using the same code.

- This is not caused by a certain JAR in the classpath. I tried to remove the first 50% of the classpath to run the test, the performance is about 110k line/s. Then I remove the last 50% to run the test, the performance is also about 110k line/s. If remove over 2/3 jars from classpath, the performance is about 120k line/s. So from the test, this performance issue just related to how many JARs are in the classpath.
- Then I tried to package all these JARs into one big JAR. Sadly the performance dropped from 90k to 60k.... So to be precise, based on my test, this performance drop is caused by how many classes are in the classpath.
- I ran the two tests on a different machine with a different file (file size and format are similar), the results are the same. So this can definitely be reproduced.

BUT I think this doesn't make sense. Did I miss anything? If this indeed is true what is the root cause?

**----------More Debug-----------------**

**GC and Perm Size**

Added `-Xmx2432m -Xms256m -XX:MaxNewSize=700m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m  -XX:+PrintGCDetails` to both tests. There are all just have PSYoungGen GC. And the performance is the same for both.

Output Details

Long CP one:

```
total speed=114k/s. curr speed=91
[GC [PSYoungGen: 247888K->16K(238272K)] 248810K->938K(413056K), 0.0003290 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
total speed=113k/s. curr speed=92
[GC [PSYoungGen: 238096K->16K(228864K)] 239018K->938K(403648K), 0.0003840 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
total speed=113k/s. curr speed=92
[GC [PSYoungGen: 228816K->16K(220096K)] 229738K->938K(394880K), 0.0006030 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
total speed=112k/s. curr speed=92
[GC [PSYoungGen: 219984K->16K(211584K)] 220906K->938K(386368K), 0.0004380 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
total speed=111k/s. curr speed=93
[GC [PSYoungGen: 211536K->16K(203584K)] 212458K->938K(378368K), 0.0005160 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
total speed=111k/s. curr speed=92
[GC [PSYoungGen: 203472K->16K(195840K)] 204394K->938K(370624K), 0.0005920 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
total speed=110k/s. curr speed=94
[GC [PSYoungGen: 195792K->16K(188608K)] 196714K->938K(363392K), 0.0004010 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
[GC [PSYoungGen: 188496K->16K(181568K)] 189418K->938K(356352K), 0.0004440 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 

......................

Heap
 PSYoungGen      total 145984K, used 81767K [0xc8560000, 0xd7780000, 0xf4160000)
  eden space 145920K, 56% used [0xc8560000,0xcd535d18,0xd13e0000)
  from space 64K, 25% used [0xd7760000,0xd7764000,0xd7770000)
  to   space 64K, 0% used [0xd7770000,0xd7770000,0xd7780000)
 PSOldGen        total 174784K, used 922K [0x5c160000, 0x66c10000, 0xc8560000)
  object space 174784K, 0% used [0x5c160000,0x5c246ae8,0x66c10000)
 PSPermGen       total 16384K, used 2032K [0x1c160000, 0x1d160000, 0x5c160000)
  object space 16384K, 12% used [0x1c160000,0x1c35c260,0x1d160000)
```

One Jar CP:

```
total speed=180k/s. curr speed=148
[GC [PSYoungGen: 87248K->16K(87296K)] 87904K->672K(262080K), 0.0005300 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
[GC [PSYoungGen: 87248K->16K(87296K)] 87904K->672K(262080K), 0.0004950 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
[GC [PSYoungGen: 87248K->16K(87296K)] 87904K->672K(262080K), 0.0005020 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
total speed=179k/s. curr speed=150
[GC [PSYoungGen: 87248K->16K(87296K)] 87904K->672K(262080K), 0.0005360 secs] [Times: user=0.01 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
[GC [PSYoungGen: 87248K->16K(87296K)] 87904K->672K(262080K), 0.0005190 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
total speed=178k/s. curr speed=151
[GC [PSYoungGen: 87248K->16K(87296K)] 87904K->672K(262080K), 0.0005360 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
[GC [PSYoungGen: 87248K->16K(87296K)] 87904K->672K(262080K), 0.0005400 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
[GC [PSYoungGen: 87248K->16K(87296K)] 87904K->672K(262080K), 0.0003510 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
total speed=177k/s. curr speed=150

Heap
 PSYoungGen      total 87296K, used 83826K [0xc8580000, 0xcdad0000, 0xf4180000)
  eden space 87232K, 96% used [0xc8580000,0xcd758928,0xcdab0000)
  from space 64K, 25% used [0xcdab0000,0xcdab4000,0xcdac0000)
  to   space 64K, 0% used [0xcdac0000,0xcdac0000,0xcdad0000)
 PSOldGen        total 174784K, used 656K [0x5c180000, 0x66c30000, 0xc8580000)
  object space 174784K, 0% used [0x5c180000,0x5c224080,0x66c30000)
 PSPermGen       total 16384K, used 2022K [0x1c180000, 0x1d180000, 0x5c180000)
  object space 16384K, 12% used [0x1c180000,0x1c379bb0,0x1d180000)
```

**JVM Initial**

I am very expecting this is the cause because this is reasonable. But after using the following code:

```
String filepath = args[0];
while (true) {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filepath), 2 << 17);
    System.out.println("Press Enter to start...");
    while (System.in.read() != '\n')
        ;
    int lineTotal = 0;
    int linePre = 0;
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long totalStart = System.currentTimeMillis();
    while (br.readLine() != null) {
        lineTotal++;
        if (lineTotal % 100000 == 0) {
            long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
            System.out.println("total speed=" + lineTotal / (end - totalStart) + "k/s. curr speed="
                    + (lineTotal - linePre) / (end - start));
            start = end;
            linePre = lineTotal;
        }
    }
}
```

Run and press enter main times, the performance doesn't change.

Comment: I tried java version "1.6.0_37", it has lot of improve. For the "lots of jars in cp" one, the speed is 150k line/s. And for the "single jar in cp" one, the speed is 180k line/s. About 20% performance drop and still can be reproduced, still doesn't make sence to me...

Comment: also worth looking into gc graph with jconsole or some similar tool. try increasing permgen size, maybe it gets full because of all those jars and gc is constantly trying to clean it.

Comment: I am wondering whether the IO system is still being thrashed during the JVM startup when your benchmark starts (eg by searching the long list of jars and scanning them); thus the JVM and your benchmark are competing for file access? A way to test this would be to run your benchmark two or three times, sleep long enough for dust to settle and then perform your benchmark for real discarding the first values.

Comment: Added `-Xmx2432m -Xms256m -XX:MaxNewSize=700m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m  -XX:+PrintGCDetails` to both. Performance has no change.

Comment: So one might guess that the manifests or so from the jars are read eagerly? What would happen if the jars were unreadable?

Comment: I updated test code to make sure JVM initial is done. The performance doesn't change during while(true) run. This is very likely. I was expecting this is the root cause...

Comment: In the One Big Jar Test, I deleted all unrelated content from manifest. The performance actually dropped to 50k. But I suppose it is caused by the one big jar somehow.

Comment: I spent some time trying to reproduce, OSX 10.8 4 core i7 laptop with SSD and Java 1.6. I placed as many jars from my maven repo onto the class path and I saw no change in performance for disk IO. Have you tried different OS kernal versions, java versions and SSD vs magnetic disks to narrow this down some more?

Comment: The host's disk is not SSD. I will try it on Windows and see. BTW, the total size of the jars in classpath is over 100m.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution but still don't know why. I run the test again using JDK 1.7.0_21, the performance of two test cases are the same, stabled at 180k line / second.

As mentioned in the question, another test is using JDK 1.6.0_37, it has performance improve but still has the gap.

So, upgrade JDK if possible.

I will be very appreciated if someone knows the root cause and tell me why :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think its down to the way you're importing the files.

If speed is an issue, always import only classes that you use.

The way to think of it is that the computer is doing more to do what it was doing less to do before.

Comment: Doing more of what, though? There are virtually no operations in the read loop that would depend on the classpath, and the obvious ones (newing a String to contain the new line) ought not be possbile to interfere with.